# jquery css continous rotate by 90 degrees on each button press

Tags: jquery, css, animation, rotation

I have found a solution that partially fits my needs. When pressing a button I need a div to rotate 90 degrees, on next press 90 degrees more etc. And i need another button which would rotate it in the opposite direction the same way. I found a JavaScript Fiddle and slightly modified it, but the problem is that on the button press the div would revert to its original position before each rotate. So its not possible to rotate it more than 90 degrees. How do I fix this? The second question is why would it rotate only once, if I change broderSpacing from "-90" to "90" (button works only once then nothing happens on click)?

[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skunksts/HwTMb/1130/)

HTML

```
<div id="foo">Text</div>
<button onclick="rotateFoo()">rotate</button>
```

CSS

```
#foo {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px; 
    border-spacing: 0;
    background-color:red;
}
```

JS

```
function rotateFoo(){
    $('#foo').animate({borderSpacing: -90}, {
    step: function(now,fx) 
    {
      $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
      $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
      $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
    },
    duration:'slow'
    },'linear')

}
```

Comment: Where is your '`now`' value coming from? You need a way of storing the element's new position (an array for multiple elements) that 'now' can ADD to the current position (or subtract when you implement the other buttkn)

Comment: The funny thing is I couldnt figure it out where 'now' comes from. I took this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/HwTMb/240/)JSFIDDLE as the basis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have made a little more straightforward example, please see https://jsfiddle.net/HwTMb/1517/

```
function rotateFoo(){
    var angle = ($('#foo').data('angle') + 90) || 90;
    $('#foo').css({'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
    $('#foo').data('angle', angle);
}
```

Also, I'm not really sure why do you need border-spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this a little and make it the thing what you want:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kermani/HwTMb/1133/)

```
    var rotate=0;
function rotateFoo(){
    $('#foo').animate({borderSpacing: -90}, {
    step: function(now,fx) 
    {
         rotate+=2.1;
      $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+rotate+'deg)'); 
      $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+rotate+'deg)');
      $(this).css('transform','rotate('+rotate+'deg)');
    },
    duration:'slow'
    },'linear')

}

function rotateFoo2(){

    $('#foo').animate({borderSpacing: -90}, {
    step: function(now,fx) 
    {
        rotate-=2.1;
      $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+rotate+'deg)'); 
      $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+rotate+'deg)');
      $(this).css('transform','rotate('+rotate+'deg)');
    },
    duration:'slow'
    },'linear')

}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="foo">Text</div>
<button onclick="rotateFoo()">rotate</button>
<button onclick="rotateFoo2()">rotate</button>
```

**Please see DEMO [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kermani/HwTMb/1134/)**

You can use this js library too [Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)

Comment: please test some number or add some condition to fix it. let me fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

Anton's answer was good a good start, but for anyone looking to rotate in two directions, it needs some work.  Here's a demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/hyrLcw0f/

```
function rotateLeft(){
    var angle = ($('#foo').data('angle')) || 0;
    angle -= 90;
    $('#foo').css({'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
    $('#foo').data('angle', angle);
}

function rotateRight(){
    var angle = ($('#foo').data('angle')) || 0;
    angle += 90;
    $('#foo').css({'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
    $('#foo').data('angle', angle);
}
```